# Tomcat 7 LinkageError Issue on EL

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

Experts,

I recently tried my Spring MVC Application in tomcat 7.0.23. The dependency management is in Maven. I get the below error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/login_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type avax/el/ExpressionFactory; used in the signature
```

The same application is working fine in glassfish. I can't figure out what's going wrong here.

Below is an extract from pom.xml:

```
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <java.servlet.version>2.5</java.servlet.version>
    <java.servlet.jsp.version>2.1</java.servlet.jsp.version>
    <java.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</java.servlet.jstl.version>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${java.servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${java.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${java.servlet.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have played around with many combination of libraries as mentioned in various posts, but still no luck. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 implements JSP version 2.2 (Tomcat 6 has JSP version 2.1), so change

```
<java.servlet.jsp.version>2.1</java.servlet.jsp.version>
```

to

```
<java.servlet.jsp.version>2.2</java.servlet.jsp.version>
```